# Addition assignment unable to concatenate strings?

Tags: python-3.x, tuples, concatenation

Getting some odd behavior that I would like to have explained.

Here I am trying to concatenate multiple strings into a variable using +=

```
MyStr = ""
MyStr += "Hello ","Word"
```

But when I try to run it instead of concatenating I get this error:

```
Exception has occurred: TypeError
can only concatenate str (not "tuple") to str
```

After testing with strictly typed types and type identifiers I have come to the conclusion that += treats inputs as a tuple.

Why?

Comment: The comma creates a tuple, nothing to do with +=

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`+=` doesn't treat input as tuples. The problem is that python treats `"Hello", "World"` as a tuple because they are multiple different objects which you are trying to group together. By default, python does this by creating a tuple.

Commas between strings work differently inside print statements, where the two are concatenated automatically by the print function.

So an easy fix should be:

```
MyStr = ""
MyStr += "Hello " + "World"
```